# Java application with Spring and Hibernate upgraded from 3.2.1 to 4.3.2 and 4.2.0 to 5.2.1 throwing error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop, spring-transactions

**Application throwing the following error:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 3

Hi we have a webapp which we upgraded to the above configurations which runs on **java 8, tomcat 8**. On the first interaction with the database(write transactions), the application throws the above error.

We have used **Spring's Hibernate Transaction Manager** implementation. We have *spring aop* defined to include the *bo methods* with the transaction and the transaction advice for the necessary actions (roll-backs basically) on certain exceptions.

**Note:** JDK and tomcat are also upgraded, both from 6 to 8

We had the same configuration(mentioned below) in the app before upgrade of Spring, Hibernate, tomcat and java which was and is still working properly, not even once we encountered this error.

Each data source, session factory and transaction managers are defined as below
    Data Sources goes like this

```
session factory configuration
<bean id="sessionFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
       <list>
          <!-- List of hbm mappings -->
       </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean> 

Transaction manager, transaction advice and aop config
<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1"/>
</bean>
<tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice1" transaction-manager="transactionManager1">
   <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
      <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="com.xyz.platformcore.common.exception.VyasaException"/>
   </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id="serviceOperation1" expression="execution(* com..*BO.*(..)) || execution(* com..*Bo.*(..)) || execution(* com..*bo.*(..)) || execution(* com.xyz.platformcore..*BO.*(..)) || execution(* com.xyz.framework..*bo.*(..)) || execution(* com.xyz.framework..*Bo.*(..)) || execution(* com.xyz.platformcore..*Bo.*(..)) ||  @annotation(com.xyz.platformcore.common.hibernate.VyasaTransactionAwareHibernateOperation) || within(@com.xyz.platformcore.common.hibernate.VyasaTransactionAwareHibernateOperation *)" />
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="defaultTxAdvice1" pointcut-ref="serviceOperation1"/>
</aop:config>

My dao method

public void invalidateSomeThing() {
    Query query = getSession1().createQuery("update SomeThing set isActive =:isActive");
    query.setParameter("isActive", false);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
getSession1() gives the Session object from SessionFcatory1 which connects to DataSource1
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Could you try to add the "primary" attribute to your transactionManager1-Bean? It looks like spring found 3 different transaction managers and don't know which one to choose.

Comment: I am afraid this might not work as excepted issue might get resolved though(we tried this). What if Spring has to pick transactionManager2 and same conflick happens and it actually pics transactionManager1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls check this out ... "Transaction manager cache fails to repopulate when multiple transaction managers defined"

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14609

Its a bug in the Spring FW 4.3.2 release. Fixed in 4.3.3.

Regards,
--Yash

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Spring documentation:

> **NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException**
>
> Exception thrown when a BeanFactory is asked for a bean instance for
>   which multiple matching candidates have been found when only one
>   matching bean was expected.

So basically, you have three Spring "beans" of `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager` with the same identifier and/or name. Eventually, you can have as many as you want, but the Spring container has to have a way to "identify" them...usually by type, then by name.

Try to log the output at startup time in `debug` mode; it will tell you step by step what are the beans you are loading up and things like that. In any case, you should have three definitions `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager` somewhere in your configuration.

Comment: we have three differeent "beans" all with different names but every bean is of same type org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager

Comment: Are you injecting them programmatically in your code? If so, you need to _specify_ the one that you want by either using Spring's `@Qualifier` or Java EE's `@Resource(name="beanName")`. I remember there is also an `autowire` attribute for the XML config in the bean's definition that let's you do that.

Comment: No we are using XML based injection as in the code posted above. we are not using the annotation driven transaction and we need 3 different transactions of same type to work on three diff data sources, Hence I doubt if `autowire` is of any help to us.